# How can I specify a directory from which to run .cgi scripts using apache2 on macos12

Tags: macos, apache, webserver

I'd like to run .cgi scripts on macos12 running an apache webserver, which uses the Sites folder as webroot by default apparently, so I'd like to put my cgi there.
I supposed I should be editing httpd.conf for this based on other threads I've read, but I find no fewer than 15 such files and at least one not found by `locate` for some reason:

```
(base) jr@Historys-MacBook-Air Sites % sudo locate httpd.conf
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/System/Volumes/Update/mnt1/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.52/.bottle/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/httpd/2.4.52/.bottle/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/httpd.conf.default
/opt/homebrew/etc/httpd/original/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/original/httpd.conf
```

those not showing the file I suspect ot be the relevant one,  `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`.
So is that latter the one to edit, or do I need to dig around in the godawful mess of .conf files that locate found?

Answer (score 1):

The file:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

is exactly the same as:

```
/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

since

```
/etc
```

is just a symbolic link to:

```
/private/etc
```

And yes, `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` is the correct file to edit here.